# Custom wordpress site and connection with database

Tags: wordpress

I am working on plesk and I try to add a custom wordpress template in a subdomain(educational reasons). So I created a subdomain "example.sample.com", I have created a database sample_db and I have attached the database to my subdomain. Then I installed wordpress on my subdomain and I tried to upload my zip file to the subdomain file, but it failed. I have searched the web and found out that my database has no tables. How do I proceed?

Comment: There won't be any tables in your database until you run the WordPress installer (if it's a manual install). Some hosts are able to install WordPress automatically for you, in which case you should try reaching out to your web host for help with this problem.

Comment: Yes it is automatically installed, but still after that it won't show up any tables.

Comment: Then that's an issue with your host and won't likely be resolved here, unfortunately.

Comment: Try visiting example.sample.com/wp-admin. Hopefully, that'll trigger WordPress' setup process after it detects that its database tables are missing.

Comment: It worked, thanks for the answers!